# Babinet's principle - equality or proportionality

Tags: optics, diffraction

By Fourier transforming $h(x)$ and $1-h(x)$ it is easy to show that 
$$ F[h(x)] \propto \delta (p,q) - F[h(x)] $$
which leads to the conclusion that an aperture and its complement gives the same diffraction patter except for the origin.

However, is the absolute intensity really the same or just the relative intensity of spots? I find it hard to imagine a small hole giving the same absolute intensity as an almost unobstructed space. Also: what happens at the origin? Surely it's not physical to have an infinite amplitude there?

Comment: Yes, it really is the same! Where in the derivation would you imagine a proportionality factor could come in? The energy balances, because in the 'small obstruction' case almost all the extra energy is concentrated in that little dot in the center.

Comment: The infinite amplitude is of course not physical. That comes about in the limit where the incoming wave is enormous, and the distance to the screen is even larger. In practice a good intuitive example is to imagine the source is a laser pointer and the screen is a foot or so away.

Comment: Lovely, thank you! Is this in any way related to the Poisson spot? @knzhou